Thread blocks main thread (Rails 5, Mongoid 6.4)
I wrote a thread as documented on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html.
Then I tried to access a model dependency.
    recalculate_archived_emails = Thread.new(company) do |c|
      execution_context = Rails.application.executor.run!
        stores = c.active_stores
        puts "all stores:"
        stores.each do |s|
          puts "#{s.name}" # so far it works
          all_emails = s.emails # hangs without error
          # lengthy computation doing something with the data

    ... 
    ensure
      execution_context.complete! if execution_context
    end
    recalculate_archived_emails.join
  end

This thread completely blocks the whole app. It seems to be unable to access the has_many dependency s.emails.
I am using MongoDB and Mongoid 6.4. Rails version 5.2, Ruby 2.7.6.
What can I do?

Any reason you don’t want to use an active job approach?

@dbugger Not really. I was just thinking, Wow, a real opportunity to use a thread! Let's learn how to do them!

@dbugger Btw, I want this done immediately. To have to configure a queue and then enqueue the job and then to tell it "do this NOW!" doesn't seem to be the right way to go about it.

That’s what you are attempting to do with the threading, without it actually working

Can this be something about the DB configuration? I was thinking that there's the main thread and now there's also the thread defined by me, and that maybe the DB wouldn't allow access by a second thread. But the stores of the company are returned correctly. So maybe they have already been loaded, and the details of the store haven't, and now the DB is asked for the info, and it says no you can't? In which case, how can I find out?

One approach you can try is to wrap the code accessing the emails attribute in a timeout block. This way, if the code hangs for too long, it will raise an exception, allowing you to catch it and handle it accordingly. Here's how you can implement it:
recalculate_archived_emails = Thread.new(company) do |c|
  execution_context = Rails.application.executor.run!
  stores = c.active_stores
  puts "all stores:"
  
  stores.each do |s|
    puts "#{s.name}" # so far it works
    
    # Wrap the code accessing 'emails' in a timeout block
    begin
      Timeout.timeout(10) do # Adjust the timeout value as needed
        all_emails = s.emails # This line might cause the thread to hang
        # Perform lengthy computation using 'all_emails'
        # ...
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      puts "Timeout occurred while accessing emails for store #{s.name}."
      # Handle the timeout error, e.g., log it, retry, or move on to the next store
    end
  end
  
  # Ensure executor context completes if it exists
  execution_context.complete! if execution_context
end

recalculate_archived_emails.join

It is nothing but wrapping the code accessing the emails attribute in a Timeout.timeout block with a specified timeout value (e.g., 10 seconds). If the code execution takes longer than the specified timeout, a Timeout::Error will be raised.
Inside the rescue block, you can handle the timeout error appropriately, such as logging it, retrying, or moving on to the next iteration.
Adjust the timeout value according to your application's requirements and the expected execution time of the code accessing the emails attribute.
This approach adds a layer of protection against the thread hanging indefinitely while waiting for the emails attribute, allowing you to gracefully handle the situation when it occurs.
Let me know if it helps.

That's a good idea, but it won't handle the original problem. I need to access the emails. The question is why I can't. It's not as if this occurs every now and then. The thread stops dead as soon as it reaches this line, every time.
